# Python code to read all the files under a folder in AWS Lambda package

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, python-importlib

I am trying to read all the files which are present under a folder in AWS Lambda package using python code.
In local code I was able to achieve it by:

```
l_files = os.listdir(path)
```

For reading the files from AWS Lambda, tried the code as below:

```
with importlib.resources.files(folder_name) as files:
    l_files = os.listdir(files)
```

But this is throwing error as attribute 'files' doesnot exist.

Is there a way by which we can read all the files present under a folder in a lambda package.

**Update**

I again tried the code as below

```
with importlib.resources.contents(directory_name) as config:
    print(config)
```

But this resulted in error: "__ enter __"

Thanks in advance for the helps

Comment: Why didn't you use `os.listdir(path)`?

Comment: @jarmod: When I tried it as above, was getting error as no such file or directory

Comment: Presumably because the `path` you supplied was incorrect. I'd update your post with your attempt so someone can help with that. There's no need to go to the 2nd code option afaik.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. But is there any way we can read it with importlib.resources modules because for reading a specific file, I was able to achieve it by read_text attribute in it

Comment: `importlib.resources.files` is [new](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) in version 3.9. Switch your Lambda runtime to python3.9.